# Extending kendoGrid with additional constructor parameter

Tags: plugins, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Following this [example](https://github.com/kendo-labs/kendo-plugins/blob/master/Web/DropDownGrid/kendo.dropdowngrid.js) I'm trying to write a plugin, or better put: extension, to kendoGrid.
My goal is to equip the kendoGrid with additional construction parameter, say: a callback function named `format`, that would provide custom conditional formatting on data change.

What puzzles me is that the example actually constructs a brand new widget, whereas I would like kendoGrid constructors to stay intact and just adopt a new parameter. I would like to avoid changing all invocations of `kendoGrid` to `kendoMyPlugin`. Is that feasible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example from your link extends the Widget class.  This is the base class from which all of the Kendo UI widgets are derived.  In your case, you want to extend the Keno Grid and add functionality from there.   You can't change the signature of the init method because this is called by the Kendo internals but you can easily add a custom option to do what you need.  The basic pattern is:

```
(function ($, undefined) {

    if (!kendo.ui.MyGrid) {    

        var base = kendo.ui.Grid;

        var MyGrid = base.extend({

            init: function (element, options) {

                // Call the base class's init.
                base.fn.init.call(this, element, options);

                // Add initialization...
                this.myField1 = options.myOption1;

                // If you want to watch changes in the dataSource 
                // attached to the grid, you could use this.  Of 
                // course you don't even need to subclass to do this
                // but you get the point.
                this.dataSource.bind("change", function(e) {
                    if (that.options.myCallback) {
                         that.options.myCallback.call(that, e);
                    }
                };
            },

            // Add default options...
            options: {
               myOption1: "Hello",
               myOption2: "World",
               myCallback: undefined,
            }

            // Add events...
            events: [
                "myEvent1",
                "myEvent2"
            ],

            // Add fields...
            myField1: "Goodbye",

            // Add methods...
            myMehod: function (a, b, c) {
                // Do something...
            }
        }

        // Register the new widget.
        kendo.ui.plugin(MyGrid);
    }    
})(jQuery);
```

MyGrid now has all the power of Grid plus your added functionality. You then create a new instance just as you did with the Grid.

```
$("#someElement").kendoMyGrid({
    // Add options for standard kendo Grid and your new options...
    myCallback: function (e) {
        alert(e.action);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks moomoo! At this very moment I'm unable to test the code, but I appreciate your answer. Looking at it, my concern would be - is the `change` event of `dataSource` intercepted and stopped or does it propagate so the user can still assign it their own handlers in the constructor?

Comment: Yes, this works like a charm! I don't even have to rephrase the constructor to `kendoMyGrid` - the default `kendoGrid` still works.

Comment: Cool! I've actually added nearly 4K lines of code to the Grid (GridEx I call it) to do all sorts of things.  Not anything I can share though.

Comment: Weird if the "options" array of your custom grid is missing the "name" property then always getting "kendoMyGrid is not a function". So make sure to have name property like:      options: {
               name: "MyGrid",
               myOption2: "World",
               myCallback: undefined,
            }